# Sensibilidad a mayúsculas y minúsculas al filtrar en Javascript y Firebase

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, firebase, web

Tengo el siguiente código `javascript` en el cual utilizo la función "keyup" de `jquery` para obtener lo que el usuario introduce  y lo vaya comparando y mostrando datos. El problema es que solo muestra lo que está estrictamente escrito como el nombre de cada producto.
Ya he utilizado `UpperCase` y `LowerCase` pero sigue sin funcionar correctamente.

```js
$('#searchCat').keyup(function() {
var refProduct = database.ref('productos');
var buscar = $(this).val();
refProduct.orderByChild('nombre').startAt(buscar).endAt(buscar + "\uf8ff").on('value', function(snapshot) {

    $(".listProductos").empty();

    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnap) {

        var snapProduct = childSnap.val();

        if (snapProduct.categoria == nombCateg) {

            $(".listProductos").append(
                '<div class="col m4 l3">' +
                '<div class="card white">' +
                '<div class="card-content">' +
                '<div class="row noBottom">' +
                '<div class="col s12 center">' +
                '<img class="card-img" src="' + snapProduct.url + '">' +
                '<h6 class="black-text"><b>' + snapProduct.nombre + '</b></h6>' +
                '<p class="grey-text">' + snapProduct.modelo + '</p>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div class="col s12">' +
                '<ul class="collection">' +
                '<li class="collection-item"><b>Precio:</b><span class="right">$' + snapProduct.precio + '</span></li>' +
                '<li class="collection-item"><b>Cantidad:</b>' + (
                    snapProduct.stock > 0 ?
                    '<span class="right">' + snapProduct.stock + '</span>' :
                    '<span class="red-text right">Agotado</span>'
                ) + '</li>' +
                '</ul>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div class="col s12 center">' +
                '<a href="#" codProducto="' + snapProduct.codigo + '" cantProducto="1" nombreProducto="' + snapProduct.nombre + '" modelProducto="' + snapProduct.modelo + '" categProducto="' + snapProduct.categoria + '" precioProducto="' + snapProduct.precio + '" stockProducto="' + snapProduct.stock + '" class="addProduct btn blue"><i class="right material-icons">add</i>Añadir</a>' +
                '</div>' +
                '</div>' +
                '</div>' +
                '</div>' +
                '</div>'
            );

        }

    });


});

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo que conviertas los dos textos a comparar a mayusculas o minusculas para evitarte el problema de diferencias y en vez de comparar uses el método [includes](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-string-includes-method/).

Ejemplo:

```
var categoria = snapProduct.categoria.toLowerCase();
var busqueda = buscar.toLowerCase();

if (categoria.includes(busqueda)) {
   // tu código en caso de que coincida
}
```